# How to prove that construction of Farey sequence by mediant is coverage?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions, farey-sequences

Farey sequence of order $n+1$ ($F_{n+1}$) can be construct by adding mediant value (${a+c \over b+d}$) into $F_{n}$, where ${a \over b}$ and ${c \over d}$ are consecutive term in $F_{n}$, and  $b+d = n+1$.

I've already prove that

- ${a \over b} < {a+c \over b+d} < {c \over d}$
- $b+d$ always irreducible in ${a+c \over b+d}$.
- the middle of any 3 consecutive term in any $F_{n}$ are mediant.
- Number of new elements added is $\phi(n+1)$.

Now I wonder does the construction by mediant value coverage all elements in $F_{n+1}$. It's easy to show that ${1 \over n+1}$ and ${n \over n+1}$ does involve in it, but I have no idea how to show that other ${m \over n+a}$, where $gcd(m, n+1) = 1$, are going to be constructed.

Please give me a hint.

Comment: Considering the [Stern-Brocot tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $0\le r\lt s$ and $\gcd(r,s)=1$, you want to show that $r/s$ shows up as a mediant. We argue by induction on $s$. Since $\gcd(r,s)=1$, there are integers $x,y$ with $$rx-sy=1$$ and $x\lt s$, $y\lt r$. By the induction hypothesis, $y/x$ and $(r-y)/(s-x)$ have already turned up in the Farey sequence, and their mediant is $r/s$.

Comment: Don’t you also need to show that $y/x$ and $(r−y)/(s−x)$ are adjacent in the previous Farey sequence. Otherwise, their mediant $r/s$ would not turn up in the construction of the next Farey sequence.

Comment: Good point. I think it shouldn't be hard to show that those two fractions are so close together that there can't be one between them with denominator less than $s$.

Comment: Having spent some time on trying to proof this and failed, I do not consider it that easy. But then again, I am not good in number theory and may have missed something trivial.

Comment: Note that I placed a bounty on this question for filling this gap.

Answer (score 3):

The gap in Gerry Myerson's proof can be filled easily indeed. It is easy to show by induction that $ad-bc=1$ for any two adjacent fractions $\frac{a}{b} > \frac{c}{d}$in any $F_n$. The key property is then that if $\frac{a}{b} >\frac{p}{q} > \frac{c}{d}$ with $a,b,c,d,p,q>0$, $ad-bc=1$, then $q\geq b+d$.

In fact, this last property has already been explained (by me) in an older MSE question : see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897178/how-prove-that-q-geq-bd-for-ad-bc-1-and-fracab-fracpq-fr/897188#897188).