# Given positive integers $b, c, d, x, y$ such that: $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{x}{y}>\frac{c}{d}$ and $ad-bc=1$ prove that $x\ge a+c$ and $y\ge b+d$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, proof-writing, contest-math, problem-solving

Given positive integers $b, c, d, x, y$ such that: $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{x}{y}>\frac{c}{d}$ and $ad-bc=1$ prove that $x\ge a+c$ and $y\ge b+d$

I was just trying to do the question above in the following way:

$ayd>bxd>bcy$ and $ad-bc=1$.

Hence we have that $ay>bx$ and $ad>bc$ and $xd>cy$.

This is where I got stuck. I couldn't continue from here. Could you please explain to me how to finish off my thought if this is possible, and if it isn't, please show another method for solving it whilst explaining the intuitive thought process behind each step?

The question as such has been answered here:[How prove that $q \geq b+d$ for $ad-bc = 1$ and $\frac{a}{b} > \frac{p}{q} > \frac{c}{d}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897178/how-prove-that-q-geq-bd-for-ad-bc-1-and-fracab-fracpq-fr) as pointed out in the comments. However I would like to know please if it is possible to finish it off using my method and if not being able to use my method fully then which part of my method could be assimilated into the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How prove that $q \geq b+d$ for $ad-bc = 1$ and $\frac{a}{b} > \frac{p}{q} > \frac{c}{d}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897178/how-prove-that-q-geq-bd-for-ad-bc-1-and-fracab-fracpq-fr)

Comment: no because  I would like to know mainly if it is possible to finish off the question using my method

Comment: thank you for your response though

Comment: I have edited to make the question clearer

Comment: Are the given integers positive?

Comment: @Divide1918 yes they are. I have edited the problem statement

Comment: How did you get your starting point?

Comment: the people which are voting for the question to be closed, could you please explain to me why you are voting for it to be closed? I believe that my question is a lot different, as what I am asking is how to finish it off using my train of thought. Could you please explain to me why you believe that these questions are the same?

Comment: @Divide1918 $acd>bxd>bcy$, this?

Comment: If this is what you are referring to then I just cross multiplied the denominators

Comment: @Michael: That should be $ayd>bxd>bcy$.

Comment: @MartinR sorry my error, correcting it now

Comment: @Michael: Note that this invalidates your further conclusions, such as $ac>bx$.

Comment: Yes, I realised right after my first edit. I have corrected it now. Thanks a lot @MartinR. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: @Michael: ... and now you can continue as in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/897188/42969 to the referenced Q&A. Are you still convinced that your question is not a duplicate?

Comment: Yes @MartinR I still do believe that it is not a duplicate, as through this question, some other problems with my proof have also been resoled, problems which hopefully will help others as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by **WolfusA**, we have
$$0<\frac{a}{b}-\frac{x}{y}=\frac{ay-bx}{by} \implies ay-bx>0 \implies ay-bx \geqslant 1 \implies ady-bdx \geqslant d,$$
$$0<\frac{x}{y}-\frac{c}{d}=\frac{dx-cy}{dy} \implies dx-cy>0 \implies dx-cy \geqslant 1 \implies bdx-bcy \geqslant b. $$
Adding two last inequalities $b+d \leqslant y(ad-bc)=y.$

Comment: Who is “WolfusA”?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :)

Comment: This is the same solution as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/897188/42969.